# Continue spawning after master client is left

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am trying to build a tower defense game using Unity and Photon. I generally find answers on the web but found nothing for this situation:

I have a spawn manager script that spawns enemies and increases a `spawnIndex` (only the master client does this). Since the master client is handling the `spawnIndex`, as soon as the master client leaves the game, another player takes over and starts `spawnIndex` back at `0`.

I tried singleton implementation with no luck. I need a way for the master client to maintain a variable and, if they leave the game, have that variable taken over by a new master client, continuing where it was left off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for choosing Photon!

The `spawnIndex` should be a custom room property and not a private field.

You can read about "Host Migration and Master Client" in general [here](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/hostmigration).

It's also preferable to set the `spawnIndex` using "Compare-And-Set" (or "Check-And-Swap") only by passing the old value as `expectedProperties` parameter in `PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomPropreties`.

Comment: Thanks for the response JohnTube,
There is countdown before spawning, it goes like 5,4,3,2,1 and spawn. Should I sync countdowns? So a client can take over when master leaves.

Comment: You can also sync countdown yes. You can use custom room property also for this. Use countdown value.